# How to receive an mp3 file from a plugin in unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mp3

I'm making a mobile rhythm game. I get songs from /storage/emulated/0/Music using Android plugin.

Get song title and music album cover

```
public class Impormation {
    private MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriver;
    private byte[] image;
    private String title;

    private Context context;
    public Impormation(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
    public String setPath(String path)
    {
        metaRetriver = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        metaRetriver.setDataSource(path);

        image = metaRetriver.getEmbeddedPicture();
        title = metaRetriver.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
        return path;
    }
    public byte[] getart()
    {
        return image;
    }
    public String gettitle()
    {
        return title;
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to return mp3 file plugin to unity.
At first, I convert mp3 file to byte[], but I can convert byte[] to audioclip in unity. I consider to convert mp3 to wav. but It's too slow :(
please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your final goal is to play the music file selected from the plugin. Since you are already able to retrieve the path of the music file. The next step is to put this music file into a [AudioClip](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioClip.htmlhttps://) in Unity. And then using a [AudioSource](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.html) to play it.

And I found this [Post](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1087000/c-script-how-to-create-an-audioclip-from-the-files.html). Though the creation of the AudioClip is been made on Windows system, I think it would work as long as you pass the correct file path on Android system.